# Why Django makemigrations detect changes everytime it is run due to accent in help_text/verbose_name attributes?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, character-encoding, django-migrations

I'm working with `Python-2.7` and got a *models.py* file with French strings (*i.e.* accented) in `help_text` or `verbose_name` attributes.

#### *models.py*

Complete [models.py is available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/12e2c5d4ae878ec0b29d). Here is an excerpt:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Checkpoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text=_('Nom du repère/checkpoint'))
    passed = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Le checkpoint a t-il était validé?'))
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site', null=True, help_text=_('Entité concernée par le checkpoint'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

#### `manage.py makemigrations`

Everytime I run `./manage.py makemigrations` I get a `AlterField` for all models' fields with an accented characters:

```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='checkpoint',
        name='name',
        field=models.CharField(help_text='Nom du rep\xe8re/checkpoint', max_length=128),
    ),
```

#### Trial #1: replace `é` and other by back-slashed equivalent `\xe9`

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elopez/apps/pycharm-4.5.2/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/elopez/projects/evrpa/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 186, in _detect_changes
    self.generate_altered_fields()
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 850, in generate_altered_fields
    if old_field_dec != new_field_dec:
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 165, in __eq__
    return self.__cast() == other
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 151, in __cast
    return self.__bytes_cast()
  File "/home/elopez/.env/evrpa/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 144, in __bytes_cast
    return bytes(func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

#### Trial #1: mark string as unicode with `u` prefix

give the same error

### Questions

How do I prevent Django migration to detect those false positive modifications?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use unicode strings for `help_text` and `verbose_name`.

Try marking the string as unicode with the `u` prefix, then find the previous migration where the verbose name was set as a byte string, and change that to a unicode string as well. Since editing the `help_text` and `verbose_name` doesn't require any schema changes, this should be safe to do.

```
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='datedmodel',
        name='created',
        field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 14, 8, 23, 349990, tzinfo=utc), verbose_name='Créé le', auto_now_add=True),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
```

There's no need for u'' prefix in migration file since it has `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Then, when you rerun `makemigrations`, Django will hopefully say 'no changes detected'.

Comment: I'm having problem with both `help_text` and `verbose_name` prefixing+editing migrations didn't solve it

Comment: I still think that switching to unicode for `help_text` and `verbose_name` name is the correct approach. Have a look at the Django apps, e.g. [auth models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py). They are using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, so all of the help strings and verbose names are unicode. Having to add `encode('utf-8')` to your strings feels very fragile. Downvoting my answer just because it hasn't solved your problem doesn't encourage me to help you any more. Hope you solve your problem.

Comment: You edited the question to focus on `verbose_name` disregarding the fact that my issue is on the `help_text`. Anyway, the `-1` was a bit harsh I admit, but your last comment make more sense than your answer

Comment: I edited the question because none of the code in your initial question used help_text at all, it wasn't done to offend you.

Comment: adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top throw `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)` on `makemigrations`

Comment: You need to remove `.encode('utf-8')` after adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, otherwise your unicode strings will be encoded as bytestrings. If that doesn't fix it, can you post your migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Appending `.encode('utf-8')` prevent the error but `makemigrations` **still detect changes each time** it is run.

```
class Checkpoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text=_('Nom du repère/checkpoint'.encode('utf-8')))
    passed = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text=_('Le checkpoint a t-il était validé?'.encode('utf-8')))
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site', null=True, help_text=_('Entité concernée par le checkpoint'.encode('utf-8')))
```